# Plotly add trace comparative

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

how can I add a comparative line to the scatter with a trace keeping my x axis.
In the first line it represents the range shown on the x-axis but the second is the previous 30 days but it is shown even though it does not have the range

[image: datastudio graph comparative]

This is my graph and my code, which currently has the other line but is in a different range and that is why it does not show

[image: plotly graph]

```
 fig = px.scatter(df_grouped, x=x, y=y, template=layout, height=200, width=530, color_discrete_sequence=palette)
 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_grouped[x], y=df_grouped[y], mode='lines'))
 fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df_grouped[x], y=df_grouped_last[y], mode='lines'))
```

Answer (score 0):

- you can prep dataframe to align previous month to current month
- then you can generate figures.  Have not focused on beautification, just approach

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "date": pd.date_range("5-sep-2021", freq="W", periods=8),
        "line1": np.random.uniform(20, 30, 8),
        "line2": np.random.uniform(20, 30, 8),
    }
)

# prep dataframe to bring previous month aligned with current month
dfp = pd.merge(df, df, left_on="date", right_on=df["date"] + pd.Timedelta("28D"), suffixes=(" current", " previous"))

# plot current month and add previous month with additional hover info
px.line(dfp, x="date", y=["line1 current", "line2 current"]).add_traces(
    px.line(dfp, x="date", y=["line1 previous", "line2 previous"], hover_data=["date previous"]).data
)
```

[image]